# console not logging post example

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb

view html page, where i want to add functionality to add list

```
 <div class="centered-content">
    <div class="task-manager-container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <h1 class="title has-text-primary">
                Lists
            </h1>

            <div class="list-menu">
                <a class="list-menu-item">
                    <p>List 1#</p>
                </a>
                <a class="list-menu-item">
                    <p>List 2#</p>
                </a>
                <a class="list-menu-item">
                    <p>List 3#</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <button class="button is-primary" (click)="createNewList()">+ New List</button>
        </div>
        <div class="task-list-container has-background-light">
            <h1 class="title has-text-primary">
                Tasks
            </h1>

            <div class="task">
                <p>This is something i have to do :) </p>
            </div>
            <div class="task">
                <p>This is something i have to do :) </p>
            </div>
            <div class="task complete">
                <p>This is something i have to do :) </p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this createNewList method is in task-service as:

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { WebRequestService } from './web-request.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TaskService {

  constructor(private webReqService: WebRequestService) { }

  createList(title: string) {
    return this.webReqService.post('lists', { title });

  }
}
```

this is method in task-view-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { TaskService } from 'src/app/task.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-view',
  templateUrl: './task-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-view.component.scss']
})
export class TaskViewComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private taskService: TaskService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  createNewList() {
    this.taskService.createList('Testing').subscribe( (response: any) => {
      console.log(response);
    })

  }
}
```

i imported httpClientModule in app.module, and the console is not logging ANYTHING (not even 404 or any error...) "Testing" which should be the body (title) of my task.
if you need any additional info to help me please say so... thank you for all of your help!

also this is in web-request-service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebRequestService {

  readonly ROOT_URL;

  constructor( private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';
  }

  get(uri: string) {
   return this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`);
  }

  post(uri: string, payload: Object) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`, payload);
  }

  patch(uri: string, payload: Object) {
    return this.http.patch(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`, payload);
  }

  delete(uri: string) {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you see in the network tab of the developer tools?

Comment: oh i see now. CORS error

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/lists' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'YOUR-DOMAIN.TLD'.
:3000/lists:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
core.mjs:6485 ERROR HttpErrorResponse

Comment: app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "YOUR-DOMAIN.TLD"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  }); this is in my app.js file

Comment: fixed it. it was this piece of code that helped :) app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    };
    next();
});